# C# program that will go through a web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I am writing a C# program that will check to ensure that all the connections it should have active based on it's web config file are active and if not it till try to restart the connection and tell the host if it fails or passes at doing so.

I have very little understanding of the web.config file I know it's XML and I think the point's I want to see are active are end points.

currently I am able to read the file but not able to just get the test after the "endpoint="

The idea/goal of the program is to let me be able to restart a connection form my web app to my database if for some reason it dropped and to let me know that I while i run this program that the connection was down.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace webconfig
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());     
        }    
    }
}
```

Form 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace webconfig
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RTBconsole.Text = "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Day + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year + "\r\n\r\n";

            // create reader & open file
            string strFilename = "C:\\Sites\\EasyeServeIDSrv\\Web.config";
            FileStream fsVideos = new FileStream(strFilename,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
            System.Xml.XmlTextReader rdrXml = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(fsVideos);

            StreamReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\Sites\\EasyeServeIDSrv\\Web.config");

            do
            {
                String current = tr.ReadLine();
                // read a line of text
                if (current.Contains("endpoint") == false || current.Contains("</endpoint>") == false)
                {
                RTBconsole.AppendText("      "+ current.ToString());
            }else{

            }
            }while(!tr.EndOfStream);

            do
            {
                // Read an item and return true
                // Continue reading as long as ...
            } while (rdrXml.Read() == true); // ... as long as Read() returns true
            // Once Read() returns false, STOP!!!

            fsVideos.Close();
            Console.WriteLine();
            // close the stream
            tr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, where are you stuck? Show us the code!

Comment: I am stuck very early on :( right now my code only writes the file to the RTB on form 1.

Comment: Also, show us a sample of what your web.config looks like and which parts of it you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: I would *Highly* advise not keeping an open connection at all times. Persisting the connection, though it may save you time in queries, will expend resources on both the client and the server (including the max connection count of your database).

Comment: the main goal is to have the program run when i tell it to not all the time and to let us know if the connection was messed up. I am seeing that sometimes a log in goes wrong do to a messed up web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each section of the web.config corresponds to a class inheriting from the `ConfigurationSection` class. Something like this should allow you to read each section of the web.config:

```
//get the configuration file
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("..."); //path to config

//get smtpConfiguration section
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("smtpConfiguration");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to query your `web.config` for elements of interest.  [Here is an example](http://www.topxml.com/rbnews/-NET-XML-System-XML/re-128462_Write-to-the-web-config-using-Linq-to-Xml.aspx) of a person writing to the `web.config` using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to manipulate the web.config using the namespace System.configuration.

There are some classes in thera that reads/writes the connection strings and app settings on execution.